# libpng warning: cHRM: invalid chromaticities

Tags: python, libpng

I did not find anything useful on the docs and on the web to solve this warning. I am using the library in Python only to load few png images, nothing more than load and show them on teh screen. Everything works perfectly apart this annoying warning:

libpng warning: cHRM: invalid chromaticities

This is the offending code:

p.s. CARDICON_1 ... _6 are png images.

```py
def drawIcon(shape, color, boxx, boxy):
    quarter = int(BOXSIZE * 0.25)
    half =    int(BOXSIZE * 0.5)
    half = half
    quarter = quarter
    half = 0
    quarter = 0

    left, top = leftTopCoordsOfBox(boxx, boxy) # get pixel coords from board coords
    # Draw the shapes
    # ALLSHAPES = (CANE, CAPRETTA, GALLINA, MAIALINO, RICCIO, TOPO)
    if shape == CARD1:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        cane = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_1)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(cane, (left, top))
    elif shape == CARD2:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        capretta = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(capretta, (left, top))
    elif shape == CARD3:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        gallina = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_3)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(gallina, (left, top))
    elif shape == CARD4:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        maialino = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_4)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(maialino, (left, top))
    elif shape == CARD5:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        riccio = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_5)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(riccio, (left, top))
    elif shape == CARD6:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, color, pygame.Rect(left + quarter, top + quarter, BOXSIZE - half, BOXSIZE - half), 0, EDGERADIUS)
        topo = pygame.image.load(CARDICON_6)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(topo, (left, top))
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please show the code and images that cause the errors,  along with the actual errors and the platforms and versions of software used.

Comment: I edited my original post adding teh source code. If I empty this function no libpng warning messages will be printed

Comment: Bad `cHRM` data can cause older integrated color-management-systems to crash. Just re-encode the PNG to fix the issue.

Comment: What do you mean save the PNG images as JPEGs (I can not) or modify the PNGs in some way?

Comment: Can you share one of the PNG images that causes a problem - maybe using Dropbox or Google Drive or some service that doesn't modify them (not **imgur**). Or can you run `pngcheck` on one and edit the results into your question?

Comment: all 6 images tested with pngcheck return this error:
invalid cHRM red point 0.67996 0.32188
so the problem is on the images not on the code. The 2 numbers are the same for all he 6 png images.
Is there a way to fix them?

Comment: I am not certain as you haven't shared any *"broken"* images. However, you could try `pngcrush -fix` or `pngcrush -rem cHRM` or loading into some image viewer and resaving them - or having a word with the person/program who created them.

Comment: `exiftool` might be able to remove it with something like `exiftool -png:cHRM=  YOURIMAGE`

Comment: Thanks guys: 
pngcrush -fix cane-128.png cane.png 
solved th problem. It worked with all 6 images.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer as it may help other folk without scrabbling around in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of comments:...

You should be able to find issues/problems with corrupt/incorrect PNG files using:

```
pngcheck -v -v UNHAPPY.PNG
```

You may be able to repair corrupt/incorrect PNG files with:

```
pngcrush -fix UNHAPPY.PNG
```

You may be able to remove chunks of PNG files using:

```
pngcrush -rem CHUNKNAME UNHAPPY.PNG
```